# Read only field - Still editable

Tags: page-layout

For a particular page layout-

Field is Read only .

I am logging in as X Profile-

Profile does not have 'Edit Read only field' permission

Profile has Create /Edit/Delete permission but does not have View All/Modify All.

What could be the reason?

Comment: What permissions sets are active for the user?
Is the field required?
There is System Modify all, and object modify all - both are disabled?

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the User profile

- Go to one of the user records.
- Click on their profile
- Then click on the System Permission link
- look for the 'Edit Read Only Fields' permission.

Comment: @Samir- The profile does not have that permission.

Comment: Permission sets are meant for extending the accessibility not restricting the accessibility. if the User's Profile does not have any access to the fields, then check the permission set

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. :)

Comment: The OP says that this field is NOT checked on the profile. so no, it should not be an answer, but it's good to have it here.